# allocating enough space for the actual length of the string

Tags: c

here's a part of my code. I'm putting some lines of my text file into array1, I chose the number 28 but it has to be a different number of each line I'm storing. I need to allocate space for the actual length of each line and I'm not sure how to find the length of each string because sizeof(str)always gives me 100.

```
   while (fgets(str, sizeof(char)*100, fp) != NULL) {

    array1[j] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*28);
    strcpy(array1[j], str);
    j++;
```

//rest of the code
}

Comment: You want `strlen` from `<string.h>`, but don't forget to add one for the null terminator.

Comment: you can use `strlen()` function of `stdlib.h`

Comment: Aside please change `sizeof(char)*100` to `sizeof(str)`. Assuming that `str` is an array, not a pointer (or array) passed to a function. That's the trouble with posting incomplete code.

Comment: Is there a guaranteed upper limit to line length perhaps?

Comment: @meaning-matters, A _string_ size can not exceed `SIZE_MAX`, so a string _length_ is less than `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: yes the limit is 100

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1.  multiplying by 1 has absolutely no effect.  Suggest removing that expression.  3) the returned type is `void*`, which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone)

Comment: so you do not have to guess as to the length of a line of input, you could use `getline()` which will give you a pointer to a allocated array of characters that is large enough to hold the whole string.

Comment: for use to perform a valid debug of your code, please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

> allocating enough space for the actual length of the string

The cast `(char *)` is not needed in `(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*28);`.
Find the *length* by using `strlen(str)` [@M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393099/allocating-enough-space-for-the-actual-length-of-the-string/46393588#comment79743283_46393099). This length does not include the `'\0'`.
Find the *size* needed by adding 1 to the length.
Allocate for the string *size*, not *length*.
Best to use `size_t` for string length/size computations.  `int` may be insuffceint.

---

The problem is like writing a *string* duplicate function.  Research the common `strdup()` function.

```
char *s96_strdup(const char *s) {
   size_t length = strlen(s);  // Get the string length = does not include the \0
   size_t size = length + 1;
   char *new_string = malloc(size);

   // Was this succesful?
   if (new_string) {
     memcpy(new_string, s, size);  // copy
   }

   return new_string;
 }
```

Usage.  `fgets()` reads a *line* which usually includes a `'\n'`.

```
char str[100];
while (j < JMAX && fgets(str, sizeof str, fp) != NULL) {
  array1[j] = s96_strdup(str);
  j++;
}
```

Remember to eventually call `free(array1[j]` for each string  allocated.

Comment: Note, you should check the return of `s96_strdup` before assigning to `array1[j]` -- otherwise, you could be assigning `NULL` as the value (which a subsequent `free` may not appreciate). Perhaps `char *tmp = s96_strdup(str);` and then `if (tmp) { array1[j] = tmp; j++; }` (side note: interesting choice of a `strdup` function name `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No problem with `free(NULL);`  "... If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs ..."  C11 §7.22.3.3 2